# Realloaction of memory in C - Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, list, dynamic, allocation

I'm starting with an array array[0] let's say.

As I loop through a text file and find keywords I'd like to store those words in that array.

So the first run though I'd assing the first keyword very simply

array[0] = "Word"

However I'm not sure how to increment that array to 1, and 2, etc.

I've read a few posts on memory allocaiton but that seemed to be specific to strings; perhaps I'm misunderstanding the concept.

I'd like to preserve the current array's contents, and increment it.

I've rigged it by setting my array[10], but I'd prefer to learn the correct way to do this.

I've included the code below so far (without any memory allocation)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include "tables.h"


int main() {

    insertVarbleTble("Name","CSTRING",1,0,"");

    return 0;
}

int insertVarbleTble(char *ident, char *type, int local, int constVar, char *constVal){
    int successful;
    int sizeArry;

    sizeArry = sizeof(varible)/ sizeof(varible[0]);

    if(sizeArry <= 0){
        varible[sizeArry]== ident;
    }else{
        successful = (searchVarbleTble(ident,sizeArry)==1;
    }

    if(successful ==0){
        varible[sizeArry+1]==ident;
    }else{
        printf("Already exists");
    }
}

void realocMem(int size){
    varible[size];
}

int searchVarbleTble(char * ident, int arrySize){
    int i;
    int results = 0;

    for(i=0;i<arrySize;i++){
        if(!strcmp(varible[i],ident)){
            results= 1;
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Header file contains the array I'm using they are:

```
char varible[0];
int insertVarbleTble(char *, char *, int, int , char *);
int searchVarbleTble(char *, int);
```

Would a potential solution be to first count the number of keywords that exist, and then dimension the array?

Comment: Once you declare an array with a dimension, you cannot change it anymore. If you need to do that, then you need to dynamically allocate memory using `malloc`/`calloc` and resize the memory with `realloc`.

Comment: Beware, strings are not first class objects in C: the are just null terminated char arrays. So `array[0] = "Word";` is almost always wrong... The idiomatic way for a resizeable string array is `char **array = malloc(N * sizeof(char *)); array[0] = strdup("Word"); ...`. But then you must not forget to free all those allocated strings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay generally what you want to do is not possible with arrays. Your code is really hard to understand but I will try to give you an example on how it is done.

This is not directly what you want, but should help you find your own solution. If you want to work with strings it gets a bit more complicated because strings are arrays in itself so you have to make sure that you always have enough memory for your current string available.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct data_container_{
    int *mem;
    int size;
} data_container;

void add_to_memory(data_container *data, int pos, int value)
{
    if (pos+1 > data->size) //check if memory for this position is allocated
    {
        int *dummy = realloc(data->mem, pos+1); // call realloc to get more memory
        if(dummy == NULL) //check if reallocation was succesful
        {
            puts("Memory reallocation failed");
            exit(1); //terminate program
        }
        else
        {
            data->size = pos+1; //set size to the newly allocated size
            data->mem = dummy; //if succesful point to the new memory location
        }
    }

    data->mem[pos] = value;

}

int main(void)
{
    data_container data; // create stuct

    data.size = 2;
    data.mem = malloc(sizeof (int) * data.size); //allocate memory, similar to an array but dynamic

    if(data.mem == NULL) //check if allocation was succesful
    {
        puts("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(1); //terminate program
    }

    add_to_memory(&data, 0, 3); //pass the address of the struct
    add_to_memory(&data, 1, 6);
    add_to_memory(&data, 2, 8); //now it uses realloc, pos would be out of the allocated range

    for(int i =0; i<data.size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",data.mem[i]); //a pointer can be accessed similar to an array
    }

    free(data.mem); //free the allocated memory

}
```

as Pablo said you should read about `malloc` and `realloc` especially you should keep in mind that the memory allocated is not initialized. `calloc` initializes with `0`.

And always remember to free allocated space when it is not used anymore.

Comment: Yeah, it was a first pass, I also don't professionally use C so it's sloppy at best. I'm essentially trying to create a hash table. I did find a useful article that I think is also a possibility that I'm reading: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/hash_table_program_in_c.htm it seems fairly similar to what you suggest; I'm going to do some more reading on memory allocation. I'm building a compiler for a graduate school project, and wanted to learn more about C. I've got it working for the simple implementation. I'll read some more on malloc and realloc. Thank you

Comment: @JohnRinderer my personal expierience with tutorialspoint was that it is a horrible source for learning, because somethings were really harmful. Maybe that changed I don't know but I think there are better sources out there.